# Don't truncate text output on Zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I find that Zeppelin is truncating my string outputs. I want to disable to that or make it longer. How do I do that?

[image]

When I check my config,

[image]

[image]

The respective configurations (`zeppelin.interpreter.output.limit`, `zeppelin.websocket.max.text.message.size`) seem long enough, why isit not working?

Comment: which interpreter do you use ?

Comment: @zjffdu its `livy`. But I managed to figure out why ... I need to set `zeppelin.livy.spark.sql.field.truncate: false`

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just to close this, the solution was to change the interpreter setting in zeppelin by setting `zeppelin.livy.spark.sql.field.truncate: false`